# Marshall Javascript Array to Seq[Any] with Spray JSON

Tags: scala, spray-json

I have a key-value pair where the value is an untyped Javascript array:

```
{"data": [1, "abc", 54.0, "cdf"]}
```

I want to convert the value to a Seq[Any] in Scala.

```
Seq(1, "abc", 54.0, "cdf")
```

So far I've tried:

```
val jsonString = args(0).parseJson.asJsObject.getFields("data").seq
print(jsonString)
// Vector([1, "abc", 54.0, "cdf"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following conversions to make the output type as Seq[Any]

```
import spray.json._

object Test extends App {
  val json: String =
    s"""
       |{"data": [1, "abc", 54.0, "cdf"]}
     """.stripMargin

  val jsonString: Seq[Any] = json.parseJson.asJsObject.getFields("data").seq
    .head.asInstanceOf[JsArray].elements.map(_.toString.replace("\"", "").asInstanceOf[Any])

  println(jsonString.length)
  jsonString.foreach(x => println(x))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me out a ton. I've been stuck on this for quite some time.